# Is new.cpp programmed improperly? Arduino 1.8.9

Tags: programming, c++, array, memory-usage

I'm having trouble with my code and I'm not sure if it's a memory allocation issue. So I look at the new, delete to see if it throws errors, and finding the source code I find outrageously simple codes. So simple, I think it can't be right.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *operator new(size_t size) {
  return malloc(size);
}

void *operator new[](size_t size) {
  return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void * ptr) {
  free(ptr);
}

void operator delete[](void * ptr) {
  free(ptr);
}
```

Does this mean if I call `customClass *ptr = new customClass[10];` it allocates only 10 bytes instead of `sizeof(customClass)*10`?

Comment: when you do `new customClass[10]` that doesn't mean `size_t size` = 10

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah... I realized that after I posted the question...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/:

> in C++, new[] is an operator with a very specific behavior: An
>   expression with the new operator on an array type, first calls
>   function operator new (i.e., this function) with the size of its array
>   type specifier as first argument (plus any array overhead storage to
>   keep track of the size, if any), and if this is successful, it then
>   automatically initializes or constructs every object in the array (if
>   needed). Finally, the expression evaluates as a pointer to the
>   appropriate type pointing to the first element of the array.